# Qt: Run function when socket connection is active

Tags: qt, sqlite, sockets, function-call

I am trying to open a pop-up window with information from a SQLite file when the file is updated through a socket connection.

How can I trigger a function call when there is activity on a specific socket?
Or is there a better way to go about this problem?

Thank you in advance for any help.  My knowledge of Qt signals is primitive at the moment.

Comment: How is the *SQLite file updated through a socket connection*? does the socket connection belong to your application?

Comment: Yes it does and I have control over it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear.

- Do you control the Socket connection? 
  If so why not add code to send a signal while updating SQL information?
- If you do not own the socket then this is not possible. Maybe you want to add a trigger on the Database and use that to catch the moment the Database is being updated.

Comment: I do control the socket connection.  I have two RPi3's communicating to each other and I want to trigger an action in the GUI when the pi receives information.  

Could you elaborate on the code to send to the Qt application?

Comment: @r0ug3Pr0gRam3r well then when you receive bytes from socket ot better when you read bytes from socket you do what you want with graphics maybe emitting a signal connected to a slot of the view controller.